# Having problems with adding an instance of a class to an empty arraylist

Tags: java, class, arraylist

So I have a `Task` class and a `Dev` class. I am assigning tasks to devs, and am logging which tasks are assigned to each dev in an `ArrayList` contained within Dev. This is my method in `Task` that assigns the particular task to the particular dev:

```
public void setAssignedDev(Dev dev){
        this.assignedDev=dev;       
        dev.addToTasksAssigned(this);  //I get a null pointer exception on this line   

    }
```

which consequently triggers the `ArrayList<Task>` in `Dev` to log the task:

```
public void addToTasksAssigned(Task task){              
    this.tasksAssigned.add(task);    //another null pointer exception here
    //sort list by allotted start time
    Collections.sort(tasksAssigned, new Comparator<Task>(){            
        @Override
        public int compare(Task t1, Task t2){
          if(t2.getAllottedStartTime()>t1.getAllottedStartTime()){return +1;}
          if(t2.getAllottedStartTime()<t1.getAllottedStartTime()){return -1;}
          else {return 0;}
    }
    });
```

You'll notice there's also a section of code in there to sort the array by allotted start time.

Now when I initialise some instances of each class and hit run, I get Null Point Exceptions when trying to add the object to the ArrayList. Main method below:

```
 Dev chris=new Dev("Chris");
Dev dave=new Dev("Dave");

Task task1=new Task("LCN","",3f,1f,5f,false,new ArrayList<Dev>(Arrays.asList(chris,dave))); 
task1.setAllottedStartTime(3.5f);


Task task2=new Task("Project","",0f,3.5f,6f,false,new ArrayList<Dev>(Arrays.asList(chris)));      
task2.setAllottedStartTime(0f);

task1.setAssignedDev(chris);
task2.setAssignedDev(chris);
System.out.println(chris.getTasksAssigned());
```

It's pretty clear where the problem is, but I'm having trouble getting round it. Why won't the object just add cleanly to the empty ArrayList?

**EDIT:** Thanks Tonga, adding the instance of the ArrayList to the `Dev` constructor got rid of the null pointers. I actually do need the last argument - there is a list of Devs and then at some point one of them gets assigned. So the `Task` class needs to hold a list of Devs to match up with.

Now when I run this the system prints out: [[Task-null], [Task-null]]
Tasks are being added but when they are returned they are null? I am expecting to see [task1,task2], am I misunderstanding something?
Thanks

Comment: `tasksAssigned` is empty or null? Have you initialized `tasksAssigned`?

Comment: Anything wrong with `Integer.compare(t1.getAllottedStartTime(), t2.getAllottedStartTime()<)`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your `Dev` class, you need to create an array list of tasks for each dev. Then in the constructor of `Dev` class, you can create the instance of the list.

```
public class Dev {
    private List<Task> tasksAssigned;

    public Dev() {
        tasksAssigned = new ArrayList<Task>();
    }

    //...
}
```

Also in your `Task` class constructor, you don't need the last argument which is an array list of devs since each task is only assigned to one dev as shown by your `setAssignedDev` method. So you need to have a `Dev` field within the `Task` class and change the `Task` constructor to remove the last argument:

```
public class Task {
    private Dev assignedDev;

    public Task(String taskName, String another, float a, float b, float c, boolean d) {
        //......
    }

    public void setAssignedDev(Dev dev){
        this.assignedDev=dev;       
        dev.addToTasksAssigned(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Tonga - I've edited my original question because your first tip worked. I'm still getting null values when I print the arrayList (see edit), is this correct?